# Payment module error 500

Tags: magento-1.9, payment, third-party-module

I recently move to a new server. During the new setup, a payment module (vpos), had the ionCube Loader which cannot work with temp URL. Message that the module work with the IP of the domain. To check if the magento works ok with orders i rename the folder in app/code/local/mage/module_name_folder so everything loads ok.

My magento site is again on air with the domain point to the new server. When i try to rename again the folder to have this module, i get error 500 in checkout page.

```
2017-05-20T09:12:12+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Mage/Empbankr/Model/Emppay.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/username/public_html/commerce/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
Mage/Empbankr/Model/Emppay.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/username/public_html/commerce/app/code/local:/home/username/public_html/commerce/app/code/community:/home/username/public_html/commerce/app/code/core:/home/username/public_html/commerce/lib:.:/opt/cpanel/ea-php55/root/usr/share/pear')  in /home/username/public_html/commerce/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
```

I have turned compilation off, cleared all Magento caches automated and manual. I removed memcached through local.xml

When it is there the onepage gives me error500, when i have a folder renamed work ok wihtout this module.

The permissions is 644.

Comment: Looks like the file `Mage/Empbankr/Model/Emppay.php` could not be found. Could you check that the include path is correct and that the files exists and is readable by the application?

Comment: @mizuti this is not part of´magento `Mage/` indicates that the extions is not correctly loaded. @Pantelis Please post content of app/code/MODULE/etc/config.xml

Answer (score 0):

Solved with merge off, when i try to enable both of them the error 500 comes to checkout page